# vb.net copy files in Folder until file is matched

Tags: vb.net

I have code that deletes files from a folder, but I need to copy files when the file = text from Textbox to a folder

My Code:

```
Textbox1.Text = 3.2.3
Textbox2.Text = 00420


Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim Folder = "C:\Windows\Temp\svn\"

    If Directory.Exists(Folder) Then
        Do Until Folder = ("*_" + TextBox2.Text + "." + TextBox4.Text + ".sql")
            For Each _file As String In Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.sql")
                File.Delete(_file)
            Next
            For Each _folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Folder)
                DeleteFilesFromFolder(_folder)
            Next
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Files in Folder:

> OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00000.sql 
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00138.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00245.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00277.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00331.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00420.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00475.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00520.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00567.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00614.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00680.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.00801.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.01062.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.01160.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.01493.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.01548.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.01680.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3.01875.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3_0.00000.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3_0.00330.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3_1.00000.sql
>   OptimumClinicals_3.2.3_3.00000.sql

[Files in Folder svn:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV2K4.png)

Comment: Don't use `+` when concatenating strings. Eventually you will run into problems, use `&` instead.

Comment: I believe that your Do loop will be an endless loop because your `Folder` variable never changes and `Folder` and the condition in the `Until` clause will never be `True`

Comment: In your `For Each _file As String In...` loop place an `If`-statement like this to stop _all_ file deletion: `If Path.GetFileName(_file).EndsWith("_" & TextBox2.Text & "." & TextBox4.Text & ".sql") Then Exit Do`.

Comment: Thanks a lot to Visual Vincent, that worked great.  Thank you.